# Работа с DOM. Игра мемоджи с поиском парных карточек

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, dom

Не могу сделать так, чтобы всегда перевернуты были только 2 карточки, при совпадении рисунков - они загорались зеленым и блокировались, при несовпадении рисунков - они загорались красным и переворачивались обратно. Не хватает опыта, чтобы верно считать индексы или обратиться к дата-атрибутам.
https://codepen.io/sophie-lamperg/pen/qBZBVEG

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    let emoji = ['\u{1F984}', '\u{1F43C}', '\u{1F437}', '\u{1F981}', '\u{1F41E}', '\u{1F438}', '\u{1F984}', '\u{1F43C}', '\u{1F437}', '\u{1F981}', '\u{1F41E}', '\u{1F438}'];
    const rotate = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
    function anima_cards() {
        // rotate.forEach((card) => {
        //     card.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        // if (card.children[0].classList.contains('anima_front')) {
        //     card.children[0].classList.remove('anima_front');
        //     card.children[1].classList.remove('anima_back');
        // } else {
        let local = this;
        let index = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i <= rotate.length; i++) {
            if (rotate[i] === local) {
                index = i;
            }
        }
        this.children[0].classList.add('anima_front');
        this.children[1].classList.add('anima_back');
        if (this.children[0].classList.contains('anima_front') &&
        this.children[1].classList.contains('anima_back'))
        for (let i = 0; i <= emoji.length; i++) {
            for (let j = i + 1; j <= emoji.length-1; j++) {
                if (emoji[i] === emoji[j]) {
                    this.children[0].classList.add('success');
                    this.children[1].classList.add('success');
                }
                else {
                this.children[0].classList.add('fail');
                this.children[1].classList.add('fail');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    rotate.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', anima_cards));

    const emojis = document.querySelectorAll('.emoji');
    const front = document.querySelectorAll('.back_card');
    function randomCard() {
        emojis.forEach((elem => {
            let max = emoji.length;
            let index = getRandom(0, max);
            elem.textContent = emoji[index];
            emoji.splice(index, 1);
        }));
    }
    function getRandom(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    }
    // function successFail() {
    //     console.log("1");
    // }
    randomCard();
    // successFail();
})
```

Comment: Хорошо бы отформатировать код в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Callback функция forEach вторым аргументом принимает индекс элемента, вы можете его пробросить до функции `anima_cards` в момент назначения обработчика событий.

Но можно сделать несколько проще.

В варианте ниже создан массив `pickArr`, в котором сохраняются ссылки на активные карты, как только длинна массива будет равна двум элементам, запускается проверка совпадения элементов по `textContent` (можно по data атрибутам, но вы их не назначаете, когда карточки создаете). Для выделения цветом в html для каждой карточки был добавлен блок с классом `.card_placeholder`, который находится поверх всех элементов карты, на нем и переключаем классы `.success` и `.fail`

Общая логика следующая.

- Запоминаем выбранные карточки (поворачиваем их и т.д.), вариант с массивом - лишь наглядный пример.
- Как только их 2, запускаем проверку (подсвечиваем placeholder и т.д.)
- Заканчиваем ход (снимаем подсветку, разворачиваем карточки, если не угадал)

p.s.
Это лишь примитивный пример ответа на ваш вопрос, в нем нет многих проверок (повторное нажатие на активную карту, повторное нажатие на отгаданные карты и т.п.)

```js
let emoji = ['\u{1F984}', '\u{1F43C}', '\u{1F437}', '\u{1F981}', '\u{1F41E}', '\u{1F438}', '\u{1F984}', '\u{1F43C}', '\u{1F437}', '\u{1F981}', '\u{1F41E}', '\u{1F438}'];
//переименовал rotate, т.к. не очевидное обозначение
const rotate = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
const emojis = document.querySelectorAll('.emoji');
const front = document.querySelectorAll('.back_card');

//массив, в котором будут хранится выбранные карты
let pickArr = []

function anima_cards(target) {
    if (pickArr.length < 2) {
        target.children[0].classList.toggle('anima_front');
        target.children[1].classList.toggle('anima_back');
        pickArr.push(target)
    }
    if (pickArr.length == 2) {
        //запускаем проверку на совпадение с некоторой задержкой, т.к. дом дерево надо перерисовать.
        setTimeout(checker, 500)
    }
}

//проверяет совпадение, подствечивает плейсхолдер.
const checker = () => {
    let color = pickArr[0].querySelector('.emoji').textContent == pickArr[1].querySelector('.emoji').textContent ? 'success' : 'fail';
    pickArr.forEach((item) => {
        item.querySelector('.card_placeholder').classList.toggle(color)
    })
    //оканчиваем ход
    setTimeout(finisher, 500, color)
}

//заканчивает ход - отключает плейсхолдер, поворачивает обратно карты, если не угадал.
const finisher = (color) => {
    pickArr.forEach((item) => {
        item.querySelector('.card_placeholder').classList.toggle(color);
        if (color == 'fail') {
            item.children[0].classList.toggle('anima_front');
            item.children[1].classList.toggle('anima_back');
        }
    })
    pickArr = pickArr.slice(-1, 0)
}

rotate.forEach((card) => card.addEventListener('click', ({
    currentTarget
}) => {
    //Если необходимо, здесь вы можете передавать индексы в anima_cards, 
    //т.к. каллбек ф-я forEach вторым аргументом принимает индекс элемента, который можно пробросить дальше
    anima_cards(currentTarget)
}));

function randomCard() {
    emojis.forEach((elem => {
        let max = emoji.length;
        let index = getRandom(0, max);
        elem.textContent = emoji[index];
        emoji.splice(index, 1);
    }));
}

function getRandom(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

randomCard();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #cfd0cf;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 42px;
  margin: 40px;
  color: #434344;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 47px;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.memory_card {
  display: grid;
  width: 620px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 25px;
  grid-row-gap: 25px;
}

.card {
  perspective: 600px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  position: relative;
}

.front_card {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #22AB93, #19668D);
  border: 5px solid white;
}

.back_card {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.front_card,
.back_card,
.card_placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.card_placeholder {
  z-index = 100;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .5;
}

.emoji {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 75px;
  line-height: 130px;
}

.anima_back {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

.anima_front {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

.fail {
  background: #F44336;
  z-index = 100;
}

.success {
  background: #5AD66F;
}

.not-active {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="memory_card">
    <div class="card" data-card="unicorn">
      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="unicorn">
      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="raccoon">
      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="raccoon">
      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="pig">
      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="pig">
      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="tiger">
      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="tiger">
      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="bag">
      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="bag">
      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="frog">
      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-card="frog">
      
      <div class="front_card"></div>
      <div class="back_card">
        <div class="emoji"></div>
      </div>
      <div class='card_placeholder'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```